# What is 502 BAD GATE WAY nginx/1.4.6(Ubuntu)

Tags: networking

I've been getting alot of these errors... I dont use nor have i ever used Ubuntu. I didnt even know such a thing existed until recently. Why and how is it showing in my phone?

Comment: Does this mean someone is running nginx or ubuntu in my phone???

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: The 502 Bad Gateway HTTP status code means that one server received an invalid response from another server that it was accessing while attempting to load the web page or fill another request by the browser.

Answer (score 3):

If you visit a bank and **request** the cashier sitting on the counter for 100$ of withdrawal from your account there are a few possible **responses**:

- You get the money (200: OK)
- They request you to go to another counter (301: Redirect)
- You are asked to show ID and it doesn't match with their system (401: Unauthorized)
- They say 'sorry the systems are down, please come back later' (502: Bad Gateway)

All these numbers are response codes used by web servers like Apache, Nginx etc. Coming to your phone, your phone is the customer to the bank while the website you are trying to visit is the bank with Nginx playing the cashier role. 
It is the bank (website) that is responsible for managing cashiers (nginx) and not the customer (you mobile).

502 Bad Gateways message means the website is having issues and there is absolutely nothing you can do about it.

PS: (Ubuntu) is the operating system where the website is hosted.

Comment: Well that makes perfect sense...cheers!